# Register viewmodel in different project from main project viewmodellocatoe in mvvmlight

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, mvvm-light, viewmodellocator

How do I register a viewmodel in a different referenced project in the ViewModelLocator class of MVVMLight. I keep getting an error when ever I try to use the SimpleIoc to register the viewmodel class because it's in a different project, and I'd Like to keep different projects for different parts of my application.

Comment: please add your code